# Which Shell should be passed to the WizardDialog constructor

Tags: java, swt, jface

In my application I want to pop up a JFACE `WizardDialog` that takes a `shell` argument in its constructor.

I tried getting a shell in 2 different ways:

1. `Shell shell = new Shell(display);`
2. `Shell shell = display.getActiveShell();`

Both ways seemed to work fine, since they created a nice modal dialogue.
My question is, which one is correct?

It makes sense to instantiate a new shell, but why should I do so if the active shell works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shell that is passed to a WizardDialog is its *parent shell*, which for example controls on which monitor the dialog will be dispayed. The parent shell has also an influence on the dialogs life cycle. If the parent shell is closed, all its child shells are closed as well (see below).

The dialog does not use this shell to create its content in. Therefore a new shell will be createed.

Therefore you shouldn't create a new shell but use an existing one. `display.getActiveShell()` works in most cases but I recommend to use a *well known* shell.

There is a possible pitfall when you open a dialog in an Eclipse workbench application (RCP or an Eclipse IDE Plug-in): `display.getActiveShell()` could return the progress monitor dialog if the happens to be open at the time the wizard is opened and will close the wizard dialog unexpectedly when progress reporting is done. The active workbench window is usually a good alternative here.